SSH telebit: can't connect to server
Having issues with SSH through telebit.
I have public key and can access my pi from local network.
When im trying to connect lie so:
ssh username@silent-dragon-85.telebit.io -v

result:
`OpenSSH_9.7p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6

debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/xavioreg/.ssh/config

debug1: /Users/xavioreg/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *

debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config

debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files

debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to silent-dragon-85.telebit.io port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/xavioreg/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xavioreg/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xavioreg/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xavioreg/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xavioreg/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xavioreg/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xavioreg/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file /Users/xavioreg/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xavioreg/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xavioreg/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xavioreg/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xavioreg/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xavioreg/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xavioreg/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_9.6p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu13.4
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_9.6p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu13.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to silent-dragon-85.telebit.io:22 as 'xavioreg'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/xavioreg/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256: #key#
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/xavioreg/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'silent-dragon-85.telebit.io' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/xavioreg/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug1: ssh_packet_send2_wrapped: resetting send seqnr 3
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: Sending SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: ssh_packet_read_poll2: resetting read seqnr 3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_ext_info_client_parse: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256>
debug1: kex_ext_info_check_ver: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com=<0>
debug1: kex_ext_info_check_ver: ping@openssh.com=<0>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_ext_info_client_parse: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256>
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: get_agent_identities: agent returned 2 keys
debug1: Will attempt key: ScreenBerry SSH Key ED25519 SHA256:#key# agent
debug1: Will attempt key: pi3Home ED25519 SHA256:#key#
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/xavioreg/.ssh/id_rsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/xavioreg/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/xavioreg/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/xavioreg/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:#key#
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/xavioreg/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/xavioreg/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/xavioreg/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Offering public key: ScreenBerry SSH Key ED25519 SHA256:#key# agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: pi3Home ED25519 SHA256:#key# agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/xavioreg/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/xavioreg/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/xavioreg/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/xavioreg/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:#key#
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/xavioreg/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/xavioreg/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/xavioreg/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
xavioreg@silent-dragon-85.telebit.io: Permission denied (publickey).`


If I were to guess the file permissions on your keys are not correct. In fact I know the file permissions on your public key are not correct.

The debug output lists several keys. Which specific key file is the remote system supposed to expect?
